# Active Admin - has_and_belongs_to_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

## Health Profiles

#### model: HealthProfile

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :health_concerns, :join_table => :health_profile_health_concerns
```

#### table name: health_profiles

```
health_profiles
id
name
```

## Health Profile Health Concerns

#### model HealthProfileHealthConcern

table name = health_profile_health_concerns

```
health_profile_health_concerns
health_profile_id
health_concerns_id
```

## Health Concerns

#### model HealthConcern

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :health_profiles, :join_table => :health_profile_health_concerns
```

table name = health_concerns

```
health_concerns
id
name
```

My goal is to access the health_concerns of a selected health_profile.

Should I create a link like this? But for this example(blood pressure), I've used a Many To Many relationship unlike has_and_belongs_to_many

```
li link_to "Blood Pressure",    admin_health_profile_blood_pressures_path(health_profile)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use **has_many  througth** association.

**has_and_belongs_to_many** can cost few issues in Active Admin.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question, nor does it offer any explicit reason to do otherwise. More detail might be of value to the community.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong here. This answer comes as a suggestion. I got in the past an identical answer from activeadmin and formtastic at the github issues page. So  it comes from personal experience and doesn't need explicit reasoning if understand that you can use the same github issue tracker as the first source of resolving your problems.